# SSRS - Format datetimeoffset value from SQL

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools, date-formatting

I am creating a report in SSRS 2019, and the SQL query for my main dataset is pulling a value that is type `datetimeoffset`. In the column where this value is displayed, the customer does not wish to see the raw value, but instead "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt" format. I have tried the following expression as the value for this column:

`=FORMAT(Fields!myDateValue.Value, "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt")`

However, when I run this report, even though every row is guaranteed to have a value, the column populates as `#Error`. I tested the expression with a `datetime` value instead, and that worked properly, but the customer wants the value passed through as `datetimeoffset`. I am also able to format the value as a string in SQL correctly, but they want it done as a expression in the report table. What must I do to accomplish this expression without causing an error on the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is this expression (or something similar to get the exact format you need):

```
=DateTime.Parse(Fields!myDateValue.Value.ToString).ToUniversalTime
```

Answer (score 0):

The Fields!MyDateValue.Value is a DateTimeOffset object, so it has c# like properties available, that a standard DateTimeOffset class has.

- Fields!MyDateValue.Value.Date >> gives you a Date Only object
- Fields!MyDateValue.Value.DateTime >> will convert to DateTime object
- Fields!MyDateValue.Value.LocaLDateTime >> will convert to DateTime in the local date time.

So if you wanted to use the Format statement you could first convert to a DateTime.

*Note: the designer intellisense does not know about these properties, so highligths as an error, but they work*

Example of what I am using for one of my reports;

=Format(Fields!ModifiedAt.Value.LocalDateTime, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")